# Using AOV on a dataframe to calculate variance among sample means - results don't match

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am practising analysis of variance in R by building a manual function for calculating F-statistic and comparing results with aov() function. But for some reason my answers are not matching. Please could you help me identify where I have gone wrong.

Here is  the data frame and code for using R's inbuilt function

```
s <- c(245,258,239,241,277,276,263,274,215,232,225, 247,226,241,253,237,246,240)
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(s, ind = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5))))
summary(aov(mydata$s ~ mydata$ind))
```

Here is the summary of the result:

```
      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
mydata$ind   1    586   586.2   1.973  0.179
Residuals   16   4754   297.1
```

And here is my manual formula:

```
#building the 4 groups
s1 <- mydata$s[1:4]
s2 <- mydata$s[5:8]
s3 <- mydata$s[9:13]
s4 <- mydata$s[14:18]

n1 <- length(s1)
n2 <- length(s2)
n3 <- length(s3)
n4 <- length(s4)
n <- c(n1,n2,n3,n4)
var <- c(var(s1), var(s2), var(s3), var(s4))
m1 <- mean(s1)
m2 <- mean(s2)
m3 <- mean(s3)
m4 <- mean(s4)
m <- c(m1,m2,m3,m4)
globalmean <- sum(m*n)/sum(n)
var.b <- sum(n*(m-globalmean)^2)/(length(n)-1) #numerator of F-statistic i.e. variance between groups with degree of freed = n-1
var.w <- sum(var*(n-1))/sum(n-1) #denominator of F-statistic i.e. variance within groups with degree of freedom = total pop - no. of groups
fstat <- var.b/var.w #fstatistic
```

my fstat is coming out to be 18.96 while according aov() it should be 1.973. The funny thing is that the book that I am referring to says that my manually calculated value is the correct one.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your probably want `factor(mydata$ind)`. Your current model is a regression, with a continuous predictor variable.

Comment: wow! thanks. That solved it. That was quick. I wasted hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Now my answers match and i'm more confident about my conceptual understanding of the topic. Thanks a ton.